# In Clause in mysql with sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, prepared-statement, where-in

I have written an mysql update query in PHP with preventing sql injections as:

```
UPDATE table1 status = 1 WHERE id IN ( ? ) and active = ?, array(implode(',' $ids), 1)
```

where id field with integer data type.

I am getting problem in executing this problem as implode generate a comma separated string and ids are not assigned with IN clause as it becomes:

```
array(implode(',' $ids) == array(1,2,3, 1)
```

first three are id's and fourth value in array is active field value but statement consider first two values from array (i.e. 1,2) to replace '?' in query

Note: there is no problem in the query as if same query without using preventing sql injection as

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 1 WHERE id IN ( 1,2,3 ) and active = 1
```

is working fine. Only issue with the PHP implode function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the sql injection when specifically cast all values in the array to int. Then it will be safe.

```
$intCastedIds = array_map('intval', $ids);
```

In case you have injecting code in your $ids array the intval will cast all values to int. So it's not possible to inject in this particular case.

So instead of:

```
UPDATE table1 status = 1 WHERE id IN ( ? ) and active = ?, array(implode(',' $ids), 1)
```

do something like:

```
'UPDATE table1 status = 1 WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $intCastedIds) . ') and active = ?', 1)
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit more as my problem is while replacing ? with actual values then query consider four values ( 3 id's and 1 value for active field) and first two (1,2) values are replaced with ?

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it still not works.

Comment: I have already solution in my mind but want to know that is there any solution for the situation which I have faced.

And thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use Prepared Statements!

Check out this article that details how you can still use prepared statements with a dynamic amount of variables..

http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli